# Highcharts - trying to start x-axis tickmark at a half hour point

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I am trying to show a series of data on a datetime axis with hour increments starting at 8:30am.  However, I can't get the first tickmark and label to start at "8:30", it always starts at "9:00."  I tried to use `tickInterval`, but it didn't make any difference.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 8, 30),
    pointInterval: 3600 * 1000 // one hour
  }]
});
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdorsey/t6yzc4xs/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `xAxis.tickPositioner` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner)) function to return a specific array of positions.

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6yzc4xs/36/)):

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
    tickPositioner: function() {
        return this.tickPositions.map(x => x -= 1800 * 1000);
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value:%H:%M}'
    }
}
```

Note that for this you have to supply a label format ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.format)), as using the positioner removes the default formatting.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked well.  I was able to tell if you start at the top of the hour or half past by doing a minutes check: starttime.getMinutes().  if the minutes were equal to 30, then I'd do the half hour subtraction on each tickPosition, otherwise, I'd just pass the tickPositions as is.